# Child component is deleted when using shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, components

I have 3 components: SemesterList, Semester and Course. 
SemesterList contains the state(array with all semesters and their content). 
In the Course component, I created a *shouldComponentUpdate()* method so as to avoid rendering a course if it hasn't changed. Without this method, all courses of all semesters re-render. 
However, after adding a course, when i modify other courses other than the added course, the added course is deleted ! 
Same thing happens when i add multiple courses then try to modify the courses that were initially present. 
I don't know why but i presume it is due to the shouldComponentUpdate() method. 
 
Here is the **shouldComponentUpdate()**:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   if (JSON.stringify(this.props.course) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.course)) {
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

I read in the React docs that JSON.stringify() is expensive but i'll overlook that for now.

Part of the render method in the **Semester** component:

```
{semester.courses.map(
   course => (
     <Course
       key={course.id}
       course={course}  
       semester={semester}
       onInputChange={onInputChange}
       onDeleteCourse={onDeleteCourse}
    />
  )
)}
```

This is the **onInputChange()** function which is called when a character is pressed and **handleAddCourse** which is called when a course is added.

```
  handleInputChange = (event, course, semester) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    var semesters = [...this.state.semesters], semesterCourses = [...semester.courses];
    var course = { ...course };
    course[name] = value;

    semesterCourses[course.id-1] = course;
    semester.courses = [...semesterCourses];

    semesters[semester.number-1] = semester;
    this.setState({ semesters });
  }

  handleAddCourse = semester => {
    var semesters = [...this.state.semesters], semester = { ...semester };
    var semesterCourses = [...semester.courses];
    const semesterIndex = semester.number - 1;

    semesterCourses.push({
      // new course's id is obtained by incrementing last course's id which is the number of courses
      id: semesterCourses.length + 1,
      name: '',
      credit: 0,
      markOver100: 0.0,
      grade: '',
    });
    semester.courses = semesterCourses;
    semesters[semesterIndex] = semester;

    this.setState({ semesters });
  }
```

Like i said earlier, i think the problem is in the shouldComponentUpdate() method because when it's commented out everything works as expected.

Comment: Print to console the data you put in `setState` in `handleInputChange` and `handleAddCourse`. What do you see?

Comment: A fiddle or sandbox link can be also useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing both `course` and `semester` props to `<Course>` component but your `JSON.stringify` comparison only checks for `course`.

Each time you add/change a course, you are creating a new copy of `semester` and `semesterCourses` using spread operator. So your existing `<Course>` components which didn't re-render are holding on to the old `semester`. That is the reason when you change any existing course the newly added ones disappear because old  `semester` and `semesterCourses` doesn't contain newly added one.

So to fix this you need to include `semester` to your comparison as well

```
if (JSON.stringify(this.props.course) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.course) &&
    JSON.stringify(this.props.semester) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.semester)
   ) {
      return false;
}
```

The above code will fix your problem but it won't prevent the re-render of other courses.

A better design would be to not pass the `semester` prop to `<Course>` component.
But if it is unavoidable then perhaps don't create new copies of `semester` and `semesterCourses` and keep your `shouldComponentUpdate` as it is.

```
handleInputChange = (event, course, semester) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  var semesters = [...this.state.semesters];
  var course = { ...course };
  course[name] = value;
  semester.courses[course.id-1] = course;
  this.setState({ semesters });
}

handleAddCourse = semester => {
  var semesters = [...this.state.semesters];

  semester.courses.push({
    // new course's id is obtained by incrementing last course's id which is the number of courses
    id: semester.courses.length + 1,
    name: '',
    credit: 0,
    markOver100: 0.0,
    grade: '',
  });  
  this.setState({ semesters });
}
```

You don't even need to create new copy of `var semesters = [...this.state.semesters];`

```
handleInputChange = (event, course, semester) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  course[name] = value;
  this.setState(this.state); // enough to trigger re-render
}

handleAddCourse = semester => {
  semester.courses.push({
    id: semester.courses.length + 1,
    name: '',
    credit: 0,
    markOver100: 0.0,
    grade: '',
  });  
  this.setState(this.state); // trigger re-render
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I have 2 questions though; 1) in which cases will this.props.semester not equal nextprops.semester (in the shouldComponentUpdate method) ?!  2) how do I know when to copy vs when to not copy(just assign reference)  (e.g when to do foo = ...bar  vs   foo = bar)

Comment: Because of this statement `semester = { ...semester };` in `handleAddCourse`, semester won't be the same in next render cycle. For #2, I suggested a hacky solution based on your problem. Generally it's not recommended to mutate the state directly, you can ignore the last part of my answer. As I mentioned in the answer, don't send the entire `semester` object to the `<Course`. Just pass semester id and do the lookup in the parent component and it'll solve your problem.